# PHP Upload timeout after settings changed, GoDaddy?

Tags: php, timeout

I've changed the settings in my php.ini to:

```
memory_limit = 50M
post_max_size = 10M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

But my script is still timing out. I've written in some code to fail the upload if the size is to large, but the upload timesout before it gets to that point. What other code can I use to fully disable the timeout, the file I'm uploading is just under 3mb so not huge?

TIA

Comment: Are you sure the timeout is those settings' fault and not your connection's?

Comment: I don't think its my connection. I should have also said that the file is being uploaded to a MySQL blob, could this be part of the problem? A mysql timeout?

Comment: *(sidenote)* There has been some fuss about GoDaddy supporting SOPA recently and you might want to consider switching hosting to a more internet friendly company.

Comment: What exactly does "times out" mean? Who times out with what message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: The PHP time limit is unlikely to be the problem if the *browser* times out

Comment: The poster made no mention of the problem being in the browser so I didn't want to assume that was what it was. I offered a solution based on the possiblity it was the script timing out.

Comment: To me, "The upload times out" suggests strongly that it's a browser timeout. But the OP needs to clarify

Comment: If someone is saying that they are changing php.ini settings to try and fix the problem, that's a pretty solid indication to me that it appears to be a script issue.

Comment: @Teeykayoh I think it's just a pretty solid indication of an OP who's trying to fix their problem using the wrong method.

Comment: I've added this to no avail. I think that the problem lies within the image processing that happens to an uploaded image to compress the image and generate a thumb. I don't think it can handle this on a larger file.